# .NET Core 2.0 and VB - Is it available on the Mac OS ecosystem?

Tags: .net, vb.net, macos, .net-core, open-source

I've been searching around and it seems like I can develop in C# on .NET Core 2 freely using Visual Studio Code. It looks like VB only comes with Microsoft's paid edition of Visual Studio (and I don't even know if VB is supported on MacOS). Is there a feasible way for me to develop a VB.NET app on MacOS using open source tools?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET Core stack itself is completely cross platform. So you can certainly write Visual Basic (.NET) code and build it using `dotnet` on Linux, macOS or Windows.

For example, on my Linux box, I can do:

```
dotnet new console --language vb
dotnet run
```

To see a working "Hello World!" application in Visual Basic.

But for a nicer editing experience (with IntelliSense and so on) the open source tool would be VSCode. Unfortunately, it looks like [VB Support is still not implemented in VSCode](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/25).

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. For web API stuff it looks like you still have to use the regular .NET framework on a Windows OS.